# JQuery example doesnt work - "Object doesn't support property or method 'button'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question was already asked in several topics, I went over them but didnt find anything helpful. Its quite simple - jquery ui doesnt work for me. I would like to use their "button", downloaded their css file and tried to implement example from their page. However, I keep getting error 
"JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'button'"

Here are relevant parts of my code. In head:

```
 <link href="/App_Themes/jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />              
    <script src="/App_Themes/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/App_Themes/jquery/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in body:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
       $("button").button(); 
  </script>
   <button>Button label</button>
```

Script is easy, but I still keep getting error mentioned above. Anyone has an idea where could be a problem?

Thank you, Jozef

Comment: Does changing your script to `$(function(){ $("button").button();  });` help at all?

Comment: Make sure jQuery UI file is loaded correctly. Check the network tab of browser.

Comment: Nicholas: it helped - button still hasnt correct style, but there is no error.

Vohuman: how can I check that JQuery is correctly loaded?

Comment: are you loading jQuery.js again after you load jQueryUI?

Comment: In chrome you can check it in the network tab, press F12

Comment: Nicholas's solution (and Legends's) should work if you load both scripts correctly ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1a59pxkc/)). If it does not, duplicate your HTML page, remove everything not relevant to your question, and post it (in your question, or in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)) so we can reproduce the bug and spot what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick ;-)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").button();
});
```

Comment: `ready` handler doesn't magically help. jQuey object still doesn't have `button` method.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: jQuery `ready` method has nothing to do with the jQuery UI. jQuery UI _extends_ jQuery core.

Comment: I highly recommend you to read about what  `ready` method does. period.

Comment: @Vohuman, the scripts runs before the dom is ready or before the button is accessible, therefore we use ready here.
But the error he mentioned is another issue, something with the script refs.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, even if jQuery can't find the element the mentioned   error shouldn't be thrown. jQuery handles empty collections silently.